# Tratar 404 no video html5

Tags: javascript, html5, html5-video

Como consigo tratar erros como 404 na tag video do html5? Eu dei uma olhada em todos os eventos disponíveis e o unico que deveria servir nesse caso era o [onerror](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_event_error.asp), porém, quando defino ele por meio de um atributo na tag  o mesmo nunca consegue encontrar minha função e no exemplo do link ali, quando da 404, ele não chama a função.

Alguém sabe como consigo contornar erros 404?

Segue exemplo no [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cLsjznbs/). Para  testar a primeira função é só por "onerror=teste()" na tag do vídeo

Comment: `onerror` não é válido pra tag `video`. Talvez addEventListener resolva. Olha essa pergunta semelhante no SO em inglês: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5573461/html5-video-error-handling

Comment: É, adicionando um listener funciona, porém, ainda sim não da pra dizer que o erro foi realmente 404 ou foi por outra coisa. Parece que ele simplesmente retorna erro só pra informar que algo deu errado, mas não diz o que deu errado

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Se for para verificar se um vídeo existe ou não, talvez seja melhor verificar isso antes de carregar a tag `video`. Se o vídeo existir você monta a tag, caso contrário monta uma mensagem de erro no HTML por exemplo.

Para verificar se um arquivo existe na internet e é alcançável por quem está navegando em sua página, você pode fazer assim:

Sem <strike>felicidade</strike> jQuery:

```
function videoExisteEEhAlcancavel(urlVideo)
{
    var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    http.open('HEAD', url, false);
    http.send();
    return http.status == 200;
}
```

Com <strike>felicidade</strike> jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
    url: urlDoVideo,
    type:'HEAD',
    error: function()
    {
        // grande chance de ser 404, mas pode ser 500.
        // você pode obter mais info se adicionar parâmetros
        // a este método e lê-los.
    },
    success: function()
    {
        // arquivo existe e é alcançável.
    }
});
```

<strike>Roubartilhado</strike> Adaptado de:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3646914/how-do-i-check-if-file-exists-in-jquery-or-javascript

Comment: É uma boa mesmo, também tinha pensado nisso, só não tinha implementado pois achava que eu que não tava sabendo usar o error do video. Enfim obrigado pela atenção e ajuda